# Cosine Calculation without cmath library

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I am a computer science student. I have been assigned a project where I need to create a small program using C++ which will ask for degrees or radians and then output the sin, cos and tan values but I can only use `#include  <iostream>`. The sine value is working fine but the cosine value is the problem. This is the code I use to calculate:

```
float rad = radian value;

float func_cos (float rad)
{
    float cos;
    int i = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    float x = rad;

    while (fabs(x) > 0.000001)
    {
        i = i + 2;
        x = -(x) * ((rad*rad)/(i*(i-1)));
        sum = (sum) + (x);
    }
    cos = 1 - sum;

    return cos;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 7):

You have `sin(x)` working? Then it's easy. [`cos(x) = sin(x + pi/2)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29+%3D+sin%28x%2Bpi%2F2%29)

Comment: since we don't have accurate value of Pi, using "1 - sin(x)*sin(x)" is more accurate ;)

Comment: @AmirNoori But you have to square root that, and `sqrt` isn't available. :-P

Comment: @Chris-Jester-Young oh mann! you're right :D

Comment: Thank you so much.. i tried still not get it.. may be i am wrong with replacing the value.. 

 func_sin(rad) = sine value;
 float func_cos (float rad)
 {
  float cos;
  float x = rad;
  cos = ((func_sin(rad))*((x) + (3.14159265359/2)));
  
  return cos;
 }
please help..

Comment: `float func_cos(float rad) {return func_sin(rad + 1.5707963267948966);}`

Comment: Mr Chris Jester Young... really thank you so much..... it is working great... :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with  "Oli Charlesworth", and "fabs(x)" function is not in "iostream" header.

Comment: Brother.. i used this code :

 double fabs (double f)
 {
  if (f < 0)
   return -f;
  else
   return f;
 }

Comment: in that case its ok :)